# Could you recommend a NLP toolkit in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, nlp

I need to parse or tokenize English sentences.
Is there any NLP toolkit in Prolog?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Attempto](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/) is IMO your best option. The parser is implemented in SWI-Prolog, and has  other tools mainly implemented in Java.

Lower level and a little outdated, from [SWI-Prolog links page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Links.txt), there is [ProNTO](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/ProNTo/). I'm sorry, I've never tried any of these components.

Prolog was born as a natural language processor: but (maybe cause it evolved as a general purpose language) today is not the preferred choice for the task. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) page, to be true very incomplete, doesn't report any Prolog toolkit.

Comment: Prolog is not the preferred choice because empirical and statistical methods have been dominant in NLP for almost two decades. Prolog doesn't support those out of the box and in fact its arithmetic is a drag.

Comment: you are right, altough ProNTO has statisticals tools, this approach seems less appealing in Prolog

Comment: "Prolog was born as a natural language processor: but  today is not the preferred choice for the task" Which language is?

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu: maybe [GF](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/) but it also isn't listed on the wikipedia page